# Why isn't there an option for First Posts, Late Answers or Low Quality Posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> Why isn't there an option for First Posts, Late Answers or Low Quality Posts on the "title bar"?

We get notifications for suggested edits - why not for First Posts, Late Answers or Low Quality Posts? This would be a helpful feature to add on the title bar. Please use this as a forum to discuss whether or not such a feature would be helpful.

Comment: Related: [Why are only Suggested Edits quantities shown in the toolbar?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223460/251274)

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills Thanks.